# REQUEST_FILENAME redirecting local images

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm developing a WordPress multisite locally and I'm wanting to redirect the broken 404 images to the production site rather than having to download them all.

I currently have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/[^\/]*/?.*$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:/live-domain.com/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which works great for the images which were 404ing and I don't have locally.

However for some reason it seems to also be trying to redirect the images which I've added locally to the production domain.

So for example:

http://localhost/files/broken-image/ -> http:/live-domain.com/files/broken image works great

But http://localhost/files/working-image tries to redirect to http://live-domain.com/files/working-image which 404s.

So I'm ending up with the reverse problem.

I thought

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Should handle this though and ignore images which aren't 404ing?

Am I missing something here?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using the code in htaccess or in a server config file?

Comment: Hey @starkeen this is in a .htaccess file before all the other rules. cheers